# Get null when posting data on an API via PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

Am working on a project whereby am posting some data to an API via PHP Curl. Am getting the response as success except that in the data Object I get null after dd().

**Data on the browser after dd**

```
  {#367 ▼
      +"request_time": "2018-12-15 12:26:49"
      +"response_time": "2018-12-15 12:26:49"
      +"status": "success"
      +"message": "All Output"
      +"data": null
    }
```

**Call the curl function in controller**

```
 $data = array(
              "from_date"  => "2018-01-01",
              "to_date" => "2018-11-01"
          );

$general = GeneralHelper::global_Curl($data,'api/v1/b2b/general/ofa/agent-commission');

dd($general);
```

**Curl Function**

```
public static function global_Curl($data, $url)
    {
        $server = env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') !== null ? env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') : env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP');

        $accessToken = session('access_token');

        $headers = ['Accept:application/json',
                    'Authorization:Bearer '.$accessToken
                    ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($server.'/'.$url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Accept:application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch)); //dd(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Fix headers: `Content-Type: applcation/json`, `Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken`

Comment: have You tried to do it using `curl -v -k -X POST https://some-ip/api...`  with flag `-v` to see if access token sent correctly and server not responding with 403 status code?

Comment: @num8er The API requires headers in teh format I have written,, according to the dd I have shown above am getting status as success but data is null

Comment: ok, again serverside app may return 200 OK and null data cause auth may not happen or maybe no data for that period or something other issue. You've to check it from other side what it gets and returns.

Comment: @num8er Where do I add this code `curl -v -k -X POST https://some-ip/api...` in the curl

Comment: run it in terminal, console, cmd, or even postman, but not php code

Comment: Okay,,, let me try

Comment: here is full curl, just replace attributes `{{NGINX-API-ADDRESS}}` and `{{accessToken}}`: `curl -v -k -X POST \
  https://{{NGINX-API-ADDRESS}}/api/v1/b2b/general/ofa/agent-commission \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
 "from_date" : "2018-01-01",
     "to_date" : "2018-11-01"
}'`   or install `postman` app and check api first: http://joxi.ru/KAgEEeh4R0ZKml  http://joxi.ru/8An33dHjBEaNrO

Comment: @num8er Tested via POSTMAN with required parameters an I  get all data,, but on curl I get null

Comment: can You tell me what headers You defined?  cause if You've defined content type json, so You've to send json object in body as in my screenshots in comments above and in curl they must be not urlencoded string.

Comment: @num8er In POSTMAN,, the headers I have set are **Accept: application/json** , **Content-Type: application/json** , **Authorization: Bearer  .....token...........**

Comment: exactly! Content-Type application/json, but in You php code it's different. So let me write answer :) 1 minute

Comment: @num8er Okay am waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send `application/json` encoded request.

It's done like this:

```
public static function global_Curl($data, $url)
{
    $server = env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') !== null ? env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP') : env('API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP');

    $accessToken = session('access_token');

    $headers = [
      'Content-Type: application/json', 
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken
    ];
    $url = $server.'/'.$url;
    $data = json_encode($data); // since content type is application/json

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

example [here](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl) and [here](https://lornajane.net/posts/2018/make-a-post-request-from-php-with-guzzle)